# How to Export radGridview1 rows data in TextBox Text Fields in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, telerik

Hi i am using Telerik WinControls to My C# Desktop application. When i am using Telerik RadgridView in event of Cell Click event I cant export the values to the textboxes when clicking the row in radGirdView. When i use it in normal grid it works fine. Only when the first row select is wroking. When I Select the second row it gives me an Exception Like this :

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Please help me thank you.

For Form Layout Click [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwXyZ.jpg)

my Sample Code for the CellClick event :

```
  private void radGridView1_CellClick(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = e.RowIndex;

        GridViewRowInfo SelectedRow = radGridView1.SelectedRows[index];
        metroTextBox1.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        metroTextBox2.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        metroTextBox3.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        metroTextBox4.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        metroTextBox5.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        metroTextBox6.Text = SelectedRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I've Managed to find the Solution.. So i thought of putting it in here for other people reference.

I found that in the line where i declare the "SelectedRow" variable i have used it to assigning SelectedRow which was defined by "GridViewRowInfo"..

Simple solution is to change the "radGridView1.SelectedRows" in to "radGridView1.Rows" and then you can specify the index that user clicked in your form.

regards